# What parts of the Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 IDE package can I delete to save memory space 

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I am starting to use Xcode 4 on a regular basis, but still find it easier to do some things within Xcode 3. I updated to Xcode 4 to the regular directory and then created another separate directory to which I downloaded Xcode 3. I then noticed that the complete Xcode 3 folder is a whopping 8.85GB!

I only develop iPhone and iPad apps. Are there any things in Xcode 3 folder that I can delete? Or move to a external hard drive and then pull back up when I need it? I could really use the space as I am on a Macbook Air.

Thanks!

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

I just noticed that Xcode 4 takes up 12.75 GB. So if anyone knows what I can get rid of there, that would be also fantastic :)

Comment: Valid question, almost 10 GB for an IDE seems excessive. But I doubt it can be lowered a lot..

Comment: Could you not have installed XC3 on your external drive in the first place? It might make access a bit slower, but at least it'll save space on your Air.

Comment: I've never done anything like that before. Do I literally just install it on the external hard drive? Or do I need to prep the hard drive someway before hand? Either way, it would be better to have both just sitting on my machine if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started off by going into Developer --> Platforms and then deleting the iPhoneSimulator.platform folder.

I never use the iPhone simulator and this folder in both versions of Xcode take up around 4GB ***each*** so I thought this would be a good start.

I haven't seen yet whether it causes me any problems elsewhere, but hopefully it shouldn't.

I'm continuing to see what other folders are not necessary and take up a lot of space.